# Replace a string like "<toto>*<titi>" with "<toto>fixed string<titi>"

Tags: bash, sed

How to (inside a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script) replace a string like `<toto>*<titi>` with `<toto>fixed string<titi>` using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), provided that `*` is a wildcard?

Comment: Both `<toto>` and `<titi>` are opening tags. Are you sure `<titi>` is always the first tag following `<toto>`?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious solution? `sed s/<toto>.*<titi>/<toto>fixed string<titi>/g`. (Why) does this not work for you? (I’m assuming by `*` you really meant `.*`.) If you want to allow nested “tags” I’m afraid regex/sed isn’t the right solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by “provided that * is a wildcard”? Do you mean “provided that * is a literal asterisk” or can * be anything?

Comment: Does `<titi>` appear only once after `<toto>`?

Comment: What kind of markup language is it? XML?

Comment: I mean * is to be anything. <titi> will appear only once after <titi>. I am playing with some kind of markup langage for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this would do it:

```
sed -E 's/<toto>[^<]*<titi>/<toto>fixed string<titi>/g'
```

...but I'd try to make sure that the opening tag `<titi>` is always the first one following `<toto>`. My [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) line will not replace `something` in

```
<toto>something<foo>another value<titi> ...
```

since it breaks at the first peek at `<` (the `[^<]*` - which means: any amount of anything but `<`) and requires that it's followed by `<titi>`

Comment: <toto> and <titi> have to appear only one time per line of source (html code), and always in this order.

Comment: @PascalCHAUVIN Ok, then this answer works for your needs.

Comment: @PascalCHAUVIN Glad to hear it! You're welcome!